# Can Apereo CAS redirect user to login page if got unrecognized ticket?

Tags: single-sign-on, cas

I have several nodes of CAS, balanced through Nginx using ip hash.
This works fine, but when I add or remove nodes, some users get "Ticket not recognized" exception.

Is it possible to make CAS delete unrecognized tickets and redirect user to login page?

Answer (score 0):

> I have several nodes of CAS, balanced through Nginx using ip hash. This works fine, but when I add or remove nodes, some users get "Ticket not recognized" exception.

This can happen in any number of ways; bad ticket id, expired ticket, removed ticket, re-used ticket, etc. What's important to remember is that when you see a ticket not recognized, that means the ticket is not managed, stored, maintained and handled by CAS anymore. It's "good-bye ticket, away with you" sort of thing.

> Is it possible to make CAS delete unrecognized tickets and redirect user to login page?

No.

As explained above, there is no need to delete things that no longer exist. If the ticket is not recognized, it is already deleted...and if the ticket is considered invalid by CAS (i.e. expired but not yet removed from storage) it will be auto-deleted. There is nothing more for you to do.

The only time you see that error message is when an application submits a ticket to CAS to validate it. This submission is a back-channel, server-to-server (app -> CAS) call behinds the scenes. There is no browser. There is no redirect. There is no login page.

What you need to do on the application side is to capture the error message, recognize it as a validation failure and send a signal to the front-end (of your app) so then it would be able to optionally inform the user and then redirect back to CAS if needed.